# Saving files in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

There are two operations on RDD to save. One is `saveAsTextFile` and other is saveAsObjectFile. I understand `saveAsTextFile`, but not `saveAsObjectFile`. I am new to Spark and scala and hence I am curious about `saveAsObjectFile`.

1) Is it sequence file from Hadoop or some thing different?

2) Can I read those files which are generated using `saveAsObjectFile` using Map Reduce? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **saveAsTextFile()** - Persist the RDD as a compressed text file, using
   string representations of elements.  It leverages Hadoop's *TextOutputFormat*. In order to provide compression we can use the overloaded method which accepts the second argument as *CompressionCodec*. Refer to [RDD API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD)
2. **saveAsObjectFile()** - Persist the Object of RDD as a SequenceFile of serialized objects.

Now while reading the Sequence files you can use *SparkContext.objectFile("Path of File")* which Internally leverage Hadoop's *SequenceFileInputFormat* to read the files.

Alternatively you can also use *SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(...)* which accepts Hadoop's InputFormat and path as parameter.

Comment: I have ran saveAsTextFile(), but it did not save in compressed format. What needs to be done to compress it?

Comment: Modified my answer and added more details for saveAsTextFile() function.

Comment: Can we apply compression to saveAsObjectFile() ?

Answer (score 1):

rdd.saveAsObjectFile saves RDD as a sequence file. To read those files use sparkContext.objectFile("fileName")

Comment: How can I read it using traditional map reduce? Same as sequence file by saying setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat) or do I need to add further customization?

Comment: I have a RDD[String] which i got by sparkContext.textFile("fileName"); I then saved it as object file by sparkContext.saveAsObjectFile("abcTest"); I then tried to read it back, by .objectFile("abcTest"), but the result type is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Nothing]; And of course I could not inspect the content of the file. what did i do wrong?